# Break key for solaris sparc with serial terminal

Tags: solaris, serial-console, sparc

On Solaris I use stop+a to enter prom
If terminal is serial console without
stop key,what is the break key?
I try

```
stty -a
```

but no break key found.

CTRL+C of course doesn't work because
only interrupt program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A serial BREAK is essentially caused by the sending device holding the Tx line low (0V) for a period of time.  It's not a character.

On a real terminal (eg a VT100) there was a key marked BREAK in order to do just that.

With terminal emulators and software it depends very much on the program you are using.  `tip`, for example, can send a BREAK with `~#`.  With C-Kermit you would press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> followed by `B`.

Now there is a problem with BREAK... if the terminal was power cycled it sometimes caused the Sun machine to think a BREAK was being sent and would drop the machine into PROM mode.  Not good.  So an *alternate* key sequence was made possible.

```
kbd -a alternate
```

Which may also be set as a default in the `/etc/default/kbd` file.

With alternate mode enabled the serial driver will treat the sequence

<kbd>RETURN</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

as a BREAK.

(That's "RETURN" then "~" then "Control+B")